# How correctly write unity type for reusable components in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm encountering issues with TypeScript types in my React component.

I have the following types defined:

```
export type UnitFormInputs = PromotionFormInputs | CategoriesFormInputs;

export type PromotionFormInputs = {
    name: string,
    shortDescription: string,
    longDescription: string,
    categories: {
        id: string,
        name: string
    }[],
    symbolCode: string,
    dealer: string,
    offer: string,
    textUnderPromotions: string,
    promocodes: {
        id: string,
        name: string
    }[],
    startDate: string,
    endDate: string,
    regions: {
        id: string,
        name: string
    }[],
    type: string,
    gradientTopColor: string,
    gradientBottomColor: string,
    isActive: boolean,
    isPassedModeration: boolean,
    sort: number,
    detailedImage: ImageData | File,
    previewInFreshPromotionsImage: ImageData | File,
    isShowInMainBanner: boolean,
    freshPromotionsImage: ImageData | File,
    isShowInFreshPromotions: boolean
}

export type CategoriesFormInputs = {
    name: string,
    isActive: boolean,
    image: ImageData | File
}
```

And I have a React component as follows:

```
interface Props {
    watch: UseFormWatch<UnitFormInputs>,
    inputName: Partial<keyof UnitFormInputs>,
    maxLength?: number,
    register: UseFormRegister<UnitFormInputs>,
    labelName: string,
    type: "input" | "textarea"
    textAreaRows?: number,
    isRequired: boolean,
    getFieldState: UseFormGetFieldState<UnitFormInputs>
}

const FormInput: FC<Props> = ({
                                  watch,
                                  inputName,
                                  maxLength,
                                  register,
                                  labelName,
                                  type,
                                  textAreaRows,
                                  isRequired,
                                  getFieldState
                              }) => {


    return (
        <div className={styles.field}>
            <p className={styles.fieldName}>{labelName} {
                !!maxLength && <span>{watch(inputName, '').toString().length}/{maxLength}</span>}</p>
            {type === 'input' && <input maxLength={maxLength} type="text" placeholder={labelName}
                                        className={`${global.input} ${styles.input} ${getFieldState(inputName).invalid && styles.error} ${getFieldState(inputName).isDirty && styles.valid}`} {...register(inputName, {
                minLength: 1,
                maxLength: maxLength,
                required: isRequired
            })} />}

            {type === 'textarea' && <textarea rows={textAreaRows} maxLength={maxLength} placeholder={labelName}
                                              className={`${global.input} ${styles.input} ${getFieldState(inputName).invalid && styles.error}`}
                                              {...register(inputName, {
                                                  minLength: 1,
                                                  maxLength: maxLength,
                                                  required: isRequired
                                              })} />}
        </div>
    );
};
```

When I pass these props from the parent component, I encounter type errors on watch, register, and inputName props. The error message is: "Type 'UseFormWatch' is not assignable to type 'UseFormWatch' FormInput.tsx(12, 5): The expected type comes from property 'watch' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'.

I've defined the useForm hook like this:
const {
register,
handleSubmit,
setValue,
watch,
control,
getFieldState,
formState: {errors},
} = useForm()

Is there a way to resolve these type errors, or should I create a separate component for my second type?

I tried to use generic  but after that I received x10 more errors

Comment: You'd get an answer faster if you made a small reproducible example. Just take all of your code and remove everything that is not necessary for someone to reproduce the issue. The irrelevant parts of the code just make it more likely that people will skip your question.